# How do I change reverse footnotes of kramdown using CSS?

Tags: html, css, markdown, kramdown

This is how I make a footnote using kramdown. (I am also working within the context of Jekyll)

```
I make a reference to a footnote [^1].
[^1]: This is the footnote.
```

This gives me the following HTML code from the second line:

```
<div class="footnotes">
  <ol>
    <li id="fn:1">
      <p>This is the footnote. <a href="#fnref:1" class="reversefootnote">&#8617;</a></p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

While I am fine with all this, I do wish to switch out the `&#8617;` character for one of my choosing (a Font Awesome character, actually). What is the best way of achieving this? Can I use CSS?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't presently an option in kramdown — at least, it isn't [listed in the configuration options](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html). (Might want to [submit a feature request](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues); the devs are very responsive.) However, there're a few workarounds that you can try, depending on your situation. Of these, probably the simplest is to pipe your output through `sed` and change the character to whatever you want:

```
    kramdown yourfile.txt | sed -e 's/&#8617;/whatever/g' > yourfile.html
```

There are hacks suppressing the `reversefootnote` class in CSS or changing the character in Javascript but it's probably better to change the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked myself the same thing; I wanted to replace the `&#8617;` (LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH HOOK) character with the `&#8629;` (DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER LEFTWARDS) character.

After some research, I found [text replacement with pseudo-elements and css visibility](https://blog.escapecreative.com/how-to-replace-text-with-css/). I ended up using the `reversefootnote` class on a private gh-page as follows:

```
.reversefootnote {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.reversefootnote:after {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "\21B5";
}
```

***Note:** `\21B5` is the css value for `&#8629;`.*

For a FontAwesome icon, I would need to declare the @font-face or upgrade the old FA I'm using before testing the icon code desired as the `content:` property value.

I hope this helps anyone coming across this old thread.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code of [kramdown](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/master/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb) on GitHub.

I found, near line 485 of html.rb `FOOTNOTE_BACKLINK_FMT = "%s<a href=\"#fnref:%s\" class=\"reversefootnote\" role=\"doc-backlink\">%s</a>"` and the last `%s` points to `@options[:footnote_backlink]`.

So just add `footnote_backlink` to your `_config.yml`.

```yaml
...

kramdown:
  auto_ids: true
  footnote_backlink: "My Go Back Text"
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    block:
      line_numbers: true
...
```

In this case the symbol would be replaced with `My Go Back Text`.

**HINT**: When `footnote_backlink` is set to "" (empty string), then the "Go back link will be omit"

When you want an icon from an icon-font, change the font-family via css.

I favorite symbol is ↰ U+21b0.

The change is also documented, in the [release notes v1.8.0](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/master/doc/news/release_1_8_0.page)